# Doxygen does not show how the documented member functions (including the constructors) are called from other classes.?

Tags: c++, uml, doxygen

Doxygen does not show how the documented member functions (including the constructors) are called from other classes. ?

I set 'auto documentation' with the EXTRACT_ALL option.
I set the CALL_GRAPH option to get the call references. 
Also I did have the graphviz/dot (output) options enabled.

Here is the log of my selections:

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Project related configuration options 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
DOXYFILE_ENCODING = UTF-8 
PROJECT_NAME = XXXXX 
PROJECT_NUMBER = 
PROJECT_BRIEF = 
PROJECT_LOGO = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = C:/Projects/doxygen 
CREATE_SUBDIRS = NO 
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE = English 
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC = YES 
REPEAT_BRIEF = YES 
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF = "The $name class" \ 
"The $name widget" \ 
"The $name file" \ 
is \ 
provides \ 
specifies \ 
contains \ 
represents \ 
a \ 
an \ 
the 
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC = NO 
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB = NO 
FULL_PATH_NAMES = YES 
STRIP_FROM_PATH = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH = 
SHORT_NAMES = NO 
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF = NO 
QT_AUTOBRIEF = NO 
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO 
INHERIT_DOCS = YES 
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES = NO 
TAB_SIZE = 4 
ALIASES = 
TCL_SUBST = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C = NO 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA = NO 
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN = NO 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL = NO 
EXTENSION_MAPPING = 
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT = YES 
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT = YES 
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT = NO 
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT = NO 
SIP_SUPPORT = NO 
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT = YES 
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC = NO 
SUBGROUPING = YES 
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO 
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS = NO 
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT = NO 
SYMBOL_CACHE_SIZE = 0 
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE = 0 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Build related configuration options 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
EXTRACT_ALL = YES 
EXTRACT_PRIVATE = NO 
EXTRACT_PACKAGE = NO 
EXTRACT_STATIC = NO 
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES = YES 
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS = NO 
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES = NO 
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS = NO 
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES = NO 
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS = NO 
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS = NO 
INTERNAL_DOCS = NO 
CASE_SENSE_NAMES = NO 
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES = NO 
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES = YES 
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES = NO 
INLINE_INFO = YES 
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS = YES 
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS = NO 
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO 
SORT_GROUP_NAMES = NO 
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME = NO 
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING = NO 
GENERATE_TODOLIST = YES 
GENERATE_TESTLIST = YES 
GENERATE_BUGLIST = YES 
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES 
ENABLED_SECTIONS = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES = 28 
SHOW_USED_FILES = YES 
SHOW_FILES = YES 
SHOW_NAMESPACES = YES 
FILE_VERSION_FILTER = 
LAYOUT_FILE = 
CITE_BIB_FILES = 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# configuration options related to warning and progress messages 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
QUIET = NO 
WARNINGS = YES 
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED = YES 
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR = YES 
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC = NO 
WARN_FORMAT = "$file:$line: $text" 
WARN_LOGFILE = 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# configuration options related to the input files 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
INPUT = C:/Projects/XXXXX 
INPUT_ENCODING = UTF-8 
FILE_PATTERNS = *.c \ 
*.cc \ 
*.cxx \ 
*.cpp \ 
*.c++ \ 
*.d \ 
*.java \ 
*.ii \ 
*.ixx \ 
*.ipp \ 
*.i++ \ 
*.inl \ 
*.h \ 
*.hh \ 
*.hxx \ 
*.hpp \ 
*.h++ \ 
*.idl \ 
*.odl \ 
*.cs \ 
*.php \ 
*.php3 \ 
*.inc \ 
*.m \ 
*.markdown \ 
*.md \ 
*.mm \ 
*.dox \ 
*.py \ 
*.f90 \ 
*.f \ 
*.for \ 
*.vhd \ 
*.vhdl 
RECURSIVE = YES 
EXCLUDE = 
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS = NO 
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = 
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = 
EXAMPLE_PATH = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS = * 
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE = NO 
IMAGE_PATH = 
INPUT_FILTER = 
FILTER_PATTERNS = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES = NO 
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS = 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# configuration options related to source browsing 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
SOURCE_BROWSER = NO 
INLINE_SOURCES = NO 
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS = YES 
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO 
REFERENCES_RELATION = NO 
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES 
USE_HTAGS = NO 
VERBATIM_HEADERS = YES 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# configuration options related to the alphabetical class index 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX = YES 
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX = 5 
IGNORE_PREFIX = 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# configuration options related to the HTML output 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GENERATE_HTML = YES 
HTML_OUTPUT = html 
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION = .html 
HTML_HEADER = 
HTML_FOOTER = 
HTML_STYLESHEET = 
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = 
HTML_EXTRA_FILES = 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE = 220 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT = 100 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA = 85 
HTML_TIMESTAMP = YES 
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS = NO 
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100 
GENERATE_DOCSET = NO 
DOCSET_FEEDNAME = "Doxygen generated docs" 
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID = org.doxygen.Project 
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID = org.doxygen.Publisher 
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME = Publisher 
GENERATE_HTMLHELP = NO 
CHM_FILE = 
HHC_LOCATION = 
GENERATE_CHI = NO 
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING = 
BINARY_TOC = NO 
TOC_EXPAND = NO 
GENERATE_QHP = NO 
QCH_FILE = 
QHP_NAMESPACE = org.doxygen.Project 
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER = doc 
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME = 
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS = 
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS = 
QHG_LOCATION = 
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP = NO 
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID = org.doxygen.Project 
DISABLE_INDEX = NO 
GENERATE_TREEVIEW = NO 
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE = 0 
TREEVIEW_WIDTH = 250 
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW = NO 
FORMULA_FONTSIZE = 10 
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT = YES 
USE_MATHJAX = NO 
MATHJAX_RELPATH = cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/… 
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS = 
SEARCHENGINE = YES 
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH = NO 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# configuration options related to the LaTeX output 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GENERATE_LATEX = YES 
LATEX_OUTPUT = latex 
LATEX_CMD_NAME = latex 
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME = makeindex 
COMPACT_LATEX = NO 
PAPER_TYPE = a4 
EXTRA_PACKAGES = 
LATEX_HEADER = 
LATEX_FOOTER = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS = YES 
USE_PDFLATEX = YES 
LATEX_BATCHMODE = NO 
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES = NO 
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE = NO 
LATEX_BIB_STYLE = plain 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# configuration options related to the RTF output 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GENERATE_RTF = NO 
RTF_OUTPUT = rtf 
COMPACT_RTF = NO 
RTF_HYPERLINKS = NO 
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE = 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# configuration options related to the man page output 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GENERATE_MAN = NO 
MAN_OUTPUT = man 
MAN_EXTENSION = .3 
MAN_LINKS = NO 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# configuration options related to the XML output 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GENERATE_XML = NO 
XML_OUTPUT = xml 
XML_SCHEMA = 
XML_DTD = 
XML_PROGRAMLISTING = YES 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF = NO 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# configuration options related to the Perl module output 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GENERATE_PERLMOD = NO 
PERLMOD_LATEX = NO 
PERLMOD_PRETTY = YES 
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES 
MACRO_EXPANSION = NO 
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF = NO 
SEARCH_INCLUDES = YES 
INCLUDE_PATH = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS = 
PREDEFINED = 
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS = YES 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Configuration::additions related to external references 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TAGFILES = 
GENERATE_TAGFILE = 
ALLEXTERNALS = NO 
EXTERNAL_GROUPS = YES 
PERL_PATH = /usr/bin/perl 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Configuration options related to the dot tool 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
CLASS_DIAGRAMS = YES 
MSCGEN_PATH = 
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS = YES 
HAVE_DOT = YES 
DOT_NUM_THREADS = 0 
DOT_FONTNAME = Helvetica 
DOT_FONTSIZE = 10 
DOT_FONTPATH = 
CLASS_GRAPH = YES 
COLLABORATION_GRAPH = YES 
GROUP_GRAPHS = YES 
UML_LOOK = NO 
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS = 10 
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS = NO 
INCLUDE_GRAPH = YES 
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH = YES 
CALL_GRAPH = YES 
CALLER_GRAPH = YES 
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY = YES 
DIRECTORY_GRAPH = YES 
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT = png 
INTERACTIVE_SVG = NO 
DOT_PATH = 
DOTFILE_DIRS = 
MSCFILE_DIRS = 
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES = 50 
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH = 0 
DOT_TRANSPARENT = NO 
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS = NO 
GENERATE_LEGEND = YES 
DOT_CLEANUP = YES
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
SOURCE_BROWSER = NO 
INLINE_SOURCES = NO 
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS = YES 
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO 
REFERENCES_RELATION = NO 
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES 
USE_HTAGS = NO 
VERBATIM_HEADERS = YES
```

To

```
SOURCE_BROWSER = YES
INLINE_SOURCES = YES
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS = YES 
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES 
USE_HTAGS = NO 
VERBATIM_HEADERS = YES
```

---

The main ones you really need to change though, are REFERENCED_BY_RELATION, and REFERENCES_RELATION.

Here is the documentation on those two options:

**REFERENCED_BY_RELATION**
If the REFERENCED_BY_RELATION tag is set to YES then for each documented function all documented functions referencing it will be listed.

**REFERENCES_RELATION**
If the REFERENCES_RELATION tag is set to YES then for each documented function all documented entities called/used by that function will be listed.